# Req.body is returning the wrong kind of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, fetch

I am sending a simple register form (POST fetch) to the backend for processing. However, the request body is not being received how it should.

I expect to see request.body = {"username": "john", "password": "password"}

But I when I am console logging it I see 
{ '{"username":"car","password":"car"}': '' }

Here is my fetch:

```
fetchRegister = (e) => { //triggered when submitting Register Info
      e.preventDefault();
      const registerOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "no-cors",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: this.state.regUsername, //The inputChange function will set these to whatevr the user types
          password: this.state.regPassword,
        }),
    }
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/register", registerOptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => 
        console.log(data)
      )
    }
```

And here is my endpoint:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const inputUsername = req.body.username;
    const inputPassword = req.body.password;

    let newUser = new User({
        userName: inputUsername, 
        password: inputPassword
    })

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            newUser.password = hash;

            newUser.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    res.send(JSON.stringify({'message': 'Username is already taken'}));
                }else {
                    res.send(JSON.stringify({'message': 'you were successful'}));
                }
            })
        });
    })
})



<div id="registerForm"> 
    <form>
    <legend>Register:</legend>
    Choose a Username:<input className="reg" value={this.state.regUsername} onChange={this.inputChange("regUsername")} required></input>
   Choose your Password:<input className="reg" type="password" value={this.state.regPassword} onChange={this.inputChange("regPassword")} required></input>
    <button className="FORMbtn" onClick={this.fetchRegister} type="submit">Register Me</button>
              </form>
            </div>
```

I just want a standard object being sent to my backend. I have no idea whether CORS or my application type is messing it up. It works perfectly fine in postman.

Comment: You forgot to add a bodyparser for json. Or, it's not running on this request for whatever reason. (`"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",` would be a good reason)

Comment: Your content type doesn't match the content you are sending.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the Content-Type problem? It wont even send if it is not that content type

Comment: Oh, it'll send it just fine. The server however won't interpret it correctly.

Comment: Which content type should I try next? I tried 'application/json' that does not work

Comment: By not work, do you mean it has the same result? or does it fail in another way.

Comment: Sorry I meant the req.body is empty with 'application/json'

Comment: That's ok, at least now you're using the correct content type, so we can rule that out.

Comment: And by it being empty, you mean it's an empty object in the server's log, right?

Comment: Yes I am doing console.log(req.body) and its and empty object

Comment: Still wondering if it is a CORS issue

Comment: well... if it were a CORS issue, you wouldn't be reaching app.post at the moment unless you were also correctly responding to the CORS preflight.

Comment: I will add my form in the original question

Answer (score 0):

It was a CORS issue. I had to install 'cors' with NPM, and bring it into Express. I could then take out `'mode': 'no-cors'` and it worked.